# Mimic right click using keyboard in windows command prompt window

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

Is there any way to fire a right click inside cmd in windows 7 without using mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to get the same result as right clicking the command prompt bar.
If you press <kbd>e</kbd> afterwards, you will jump to `edit` where you can find the same options as right clicking the command prompt window.

Comment: Please explain how this actually answers the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill if I undrtstood right, he wants to run a mouse right click from cmd. He can call this script and that will do the job

Comment: Shame it doesn't work then. I've just tested it on Windows 7 64 bit. Running that vbs script does nothing at all.

Comment: @DavidPostill - yup, from CMD window it isn't working. Updated answer with another method.